# In MSAccess2007 auto update 'years of experience' field and

Tags: database-design, ms-access-2007

In MSAccess2007 can you have a field which has years/months of experience which autoupdates as time passes? Its similar to the website linkedin, where it updates the time served in your current employment position.

Also can you create a search form which then looks up for rows which shows 'x' amount of years or more.

The reasoning behind this is to have a database of people, with years of experience for certain industries, and if I want to search for people with 'x' amount of years experience or more, I can search for it by typing what I want in a form.

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think having an 'autoupdate' is a good idea unless it's 100% bulletproof - you don't want it to run twice in a row. An alternative approach is to have their 'start year & month' in your DB, then your query can calculate the years of experience based on the difference between their date and the current date.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That sounds perfect, how would I do that?

Comment: Here is a simple query that calculates TWO values - one is Years and the other is Months - based on the difference between a date in a dable and today.
SELECT Staffing.SDAte, Staffing.Edate, DateDiff("yyyy",[Sdate],Date()) AS Yrs, DateDiff("m",[sdate],Date()) AS Mths
FROM Staffing;

Comment: is  possible to show date and months. Ive been playing with the datediff function in the control source for about 20mins trying to do this but can only get one or the other?

Comment: Check this out .. [Calculate Exact Difference](http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/Diff2Dates.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to show Years, Months, Days difference between two dates (I used Current Date as end date - you can use value from your table if desired):

```
SELECT Staffing.SDAte, Staffing.Edate, 
DateDiff("yyyy",[SDAte],Date())-IIf(Format([SDAte],"mmdd")>Format(Date(),"mmdd"),1,0)
AS Years,
IIf(Day([SDAte])<=Day(Date()),DateDiff("m",[SDAte],Date())-[Years]*12,DateDiff("m",[SDAte],Date ())-[Years]*12-1)
 AS Months,
 DateDiff("d",DateAdd("m",[Months],DateAdd("yyyy",[Years],[SDAte])),Date())
 AS Days
FROM Staffing;
```